# Shift data from a row into a column

Tags: vba, excel

I have a row of data that looks like the below.

```
IBM RPA|Reading|ATC01789|ATC01790|C4966572|NT018258 etc.
```

My question is how do i move the the data to look like the following?

```
IBM RPA|Reading|ATC01789
                ATC01790
                C4966572
                NT018258
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are basically looking for Transponse,  something like this:

```
Dim X() As Variant
Dim XT() As Variant
X = ActiveSheet.Range("RangeOfRow").Value2
XT = Application.Transpose(X)
ActiveSheet.Range("RangeOfColum").Value = XT
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Works Perfectly